# Rails db query to find and sort posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

My app has designs that users can like (vote, using acts_as_voteable). To find a design's like count in the view, you use

```
@design.votes.count
```

I'm making a popular page to showcase the most popular designs based on the number of votes they have. I only want designs that has at least 5 votes to them. Right now, I had that in the view but I want to push that into the controller. My controller, thus far, looks like this which shows all the designs and sorts them in order of most votes.

```
def popular
  @designs = Design.all
  @designs.sort! {|t1, t2| t2.votes.count <=> t1.votes.count}
end
```

Now i just want to make sure the designs have a minimum vote count of 5.

Previously, I was doing this the wrong way and putting it in my view by putting this inside my Design loop

```
<% if design.vote.count > 5 %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the behavior you want is better defined in the Design model and not in the controller since it deals with data. So in your Design model, add the following code:

```
scope :most_popular, -> do 
  results = select {|design| design.votes.count > 4 }
  results.sort! {|t1, t2| t2.votes.count <=> t1.votes.count}
end
```

Adding the two scope methods above in your Design model, you could do this in your controller code:

```
def popular
  @designs = Design.most_popular
end
```

Your controller code ends up being a lot cleaner and you have scope methods that you can reuse anywhere else you need them. :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes! that's it! Thanks so much @Gjaldon! You definitely helped solve the problem and now it's clear to put that behavior in the model. Much appreciation. Enjoy the bounty when it lets me award it in about 9 hours

Comment: Now I will say the order_by_popularity isn't working in the model but when I put that code into the controller like I had it, it works. Right now I have `@designs = Design.most_popular` `@designs.sort! ..... ` and that works, but the `Design.most_popular.order_by_popularity` gives me this error `undefined method "order_by_popularity" for #<Array:0x0000010260e5c0>`

Comment: I'm glad you find it useful! Looks like most_popular is returning an array so I'll just move it inside the :most_popular scope method instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a having() clause. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having

For example: Design.joins(:votes).group('votes.design_id').having('votes.count > 5').order('votes.count')

**Edit**

You can also just use a where clause. For example, for the first design:

Design.first.votes.where('count > 5')

Example for multiple designs:

Design.all.map{ |a| a.votes.where('count > 5').count }.sort! # returns a sorted array with all vote counts

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm actually getting an error with that and I've tried a few different things like that but keep getting an error each time. `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "designs.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Did you actually setup your relationship? As in: a Design has_many :votes and a Vote belongs_to :design. The vote table should have a design_id.

Comment: With the acts_as_voteable gem, to setup the relationship in the DesignModel you just use `acts_as_voteable`

Comment: Votes have a voteable_id and voteable_type as it's polymorphic because multiple models get voted on. To make the problem easier, I just asked about one model, Design, to find that query

Comment: I forgot grouping. You need to group before using having. P.s. You can use whatever you want as grouping column, I just gave an example.

Comment: Yea even using the newer grouping and using voteable_id in place of design_id, i keep getting that same error where `"designs.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: Probably has to do with the polymorphic relationship. I had a working sample application with has_many and belongs_to. Btw, I added another approach.

Comment: Alright well I appreciate your help a lot! I will keep at it until I figure it out. Cheers!

Comment: Well, you can try the second approach in the edit part of my question. If I get you in the right direction, please mark my answer as useful.

Comment: I will. I think you're right...I should have just build the votes from scratch instead of using the gem. Thanks @Peter